# Distribution unknown

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have search whole internet,every single page of my book.I ask my friends i didn't find everywhere a solution of this exercise and i can't understand what distribution is .The exercise says:

One internet company have **4** servers.

The **2** servers there is the database.

The other **2** servers are running the software.

The possibility of something goes wrong, in every server is 1%(for the next year).We know that every server **is independent**(meaning  if 1 server  doesn't work well,it will not influence the other server).If the internet company ,must working  properly ,must working **at least 1** from the servers of database and **at least 1** server from the running of the software.What is the possibility of working properly the internet company the next year?

Thanks in advance.If someone can solve it and explain me what it is i am greatful.My mind can't think is Posion,nor Bernuli,not Geometry etc.Is this a distribution?

Comment: This is just a discrete system.  The probability that at least one of the database servers is working is $1-.01^2$.  Same for the software servers.  You need both of these to hold so...

Comment: moment to google what it is discrete system

Comment: @lulu could you explain me how you find it so easily 1−.01^2 ?

Comment: I just mean, there are only finitely many states.  Like rolling a die.  There are two states for each die, so there are exactly $2^4=16$ possible states.  In a pinch, just write them all out.

Comment: The complement of the event "at least one server of the two is working" is "both are broken".  The probability that both are broken is $.01^2$ so....

Comment: wow i have been amaized!If it wasn't 1% and it was 5% then it will be 0.5^2?

Comment: Well, $.05^2$. $\quad$

Comment: thank you a lot but if i have lets say 5 servers and wanted 2 servers with 5%?then what?

Comment: To practice, work it out the long way.  Say the two servers are $A,B$.  Figure out the probabilities that: $1:$ $A$ is working and $B$ isn't.  $2:$ $B$ is working but $A$ isn't.  and $3:$ Both are working.  Add those up.  Should get the same answer.

Comment: If you get any basic text on discrete probability you should find dozens of good examples to work out.

Comment: man really i couldn't beleive how easy it was hahahah you are awesome really

Comment: @lulu i have and one more same exercise but it is little more confusing,but i have 5 servers now.5%.But from the 3 servers are working  70% the days of one year.Now what i am gonna do? and it tells me the two to be working.With your method 2^5=32 possible states.0.5^2 .What about 70% ? in this case?

Comment: That's hard to follow.  I suggest posting a separate question.

Comment: ok roger that :)